# how to move the last digit in the first position in C++ without using if statement

Tags: c++, visual-c++

**for eg
123==
312
how to move the last digit in the first position in C++ without using if statement

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main(){
        int n=123;
        
        while(n!=0){
          
        }
        cout<<n;//==312
    }
```

Comment: Hint: you can use `while (condition) { /* statements*/ break; }` instead of `if (condition) { /* statements */ }` (be careful because `break;` and `continue` in `while` works differ than one in `if`)

Comment: show me the code then

Comment: Can we have more information? Is the number guaranteed to only be 3 digits? are you allowed to make make `n` a string? Maybe it would be helpful to show whatever example you have which does use an `if` statement.

Comment: Can you take the input as a `string` and leave it as a `string`? If you can, `std::rotate` is your bestest of friends. Very often if you don't need to perform math on a number it will be more tractable as a `string`.

Comment: it can be any number no limits

Comment: @Eyou_tady welcome to SO! Note that it is not "do it for me" service. Please take a look at ["How to ask a good question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `auto s = to_string(n); char c = s.back(); s.pop_back(); s = c + s; n = stoi(s);` ... but user4581301's [`std::rotate`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZmeDQL4LaE) is even better.  Negative numbers may need a tweak.

Comment: You should treat the number as string when there is no limit about its size because integer types in C++ can handle only limited range.

Comment: @Eyou_tady please read this before asking a question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by

1. Get the last digit and the other digits
2. Find the position of the digit that is next to the other digits
3. Place the last digit there

```
#include <iostream>

int moveDigit(int n) {
    int res = n / 10;
    int delta = 1;
    while (delta <= res) delta *= 10;
    return (n % 10) * delta + res;
}

int main(){
    int n=123;
    
    n = moveDigit(n);
    
    std::cout<<n;//==312
}
```

With the function inlined:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int n=123;
    
    int res = n / 10;
    int delta = 1;
    while (delta <= res) delta *= 10;
    n = (n % 10) * delta + res;
    
    std::cout<<n;//==312
}
```

Comment: I can't use functions I'm only allowed to loop

Comment: @Eyou_tady can't you just use the code in the function directly in `main`? How exactly are you supposed to use a loop? Can you provide the full list of instructions so nobody has to write an answer and then find out that doesn't meet the requirements?

Comment: @Eyou_tady Inline version added.

Answer (score 0):

I'll probably get some hate for this

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <utility>
int main() {
 int n =123;
 std::string n_s{std::to_string(n)};
 std::swap(n_s.front(), n_s.back());
 n=std::stoi(n_s);
}
```

Comment: Perfectly good approach, but as Sean Parent would say; That’s a (std::)rotate. It’s not just a swap.

Comment: I was fairly certain i was circumventing what the OP actually needs to do. Instead i wrote the bare minimum to meet what was asked for. Btw, i had to look up the reference. I'm pretty new the c++ culture.